# HTML5 audio tag in Django template do not work properly in Safari

Tags: django, safari, http-headers, html5-audio

I've created simple index.html file in some local folder with content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio controls>
        <source src="example.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works and looks fine in any browser. In Safari:

[image: Safari audio example]

But when I do exactly the same page in Django using TemplateView:

```
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base.html'), name='base'),
```

I get:

[image: Safari audio example with live broadcast]

It works - audio plays, but no progress bar, time remaining, etc.

So, the only difference is that Safari via Django does not determine audio file duration and treats it like Live Broadcast. I guess that some http header should be passed somewhere, but it is just guesses

---

Static files serves by Django in `DEBUG = True`

Everything is fine in Chrome, FF and Opera (both in local and django files)

---

Safari version: 10.1.1 (Latest for now)

Django version: 1.11.1 (Latest for now)

Comment: Well there is no such thing as a `django html element`. What you have is a misbehaving HTML markup

Comment: I've encountered issues in Django with streaming static content like videos and audio. These issues seem to go away once an nginx server is deployed to handle the static files. If it looks fine in production it's not really a big deal.